# error when switching to directory: "perl version 5.12.3 can't run /usr/bin/shasum"

Tags: ruby, macos, perl, rvm

I installed rvm 1.9.3 and now whenever I switch to a directory containing a `.rvmrc`, I get a perl error message:

```
~/example$ cd .. && cd example

perl version 5.12.3 can't run /usr/bin/shasum.  Try the alternative(s):

/usr/bin/shasum5.10.0 (uses perl 5.10.0)

Run "man perl" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
```

Comment: I think I figured out the cause, but I have no idea what the solution is. In OSX, `/usr/bin/perl` is a wrapper that calls either `perl5.12` or `perl5.10`. In turn, those guys call the appropriate shasum (`shasum5.12` or `shasum5.10`). I managed to **break** my installation by trying to upgrade my perl to 5.16. Bad Me! Searching the internet, I see lots of descriptions of this same problem, but no solution. ***Maybe*** if you had your OSX original media you could restore `/usr/bin/perl`. If you don't, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this dirty approach. This approach will skip those check and directly use shasum in your binary directory

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ls shasum*
  shasum shasum5.10.0
$ mv /usr/bin/shasum /usr/bin/your_backup_shasum
$ ln -s shasum5.10.0 shasum
```